# How to solve and understand this opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics

Here I have this portion of the circuit which I can't really understand what it is doing and I want to solve it, so I can understand it.

The inverting input is having a 2 signals and their peak is 5V. While on this inverting input we have this transistor with analog switch. The analog switch is being switched by a delay signal whose on-time is 50µs. This is the portion I am confused about. So I want tips/suggestions to how to understand this circuit and how to solve it, so I could understand why they used this transistor and switch part in this circuit. The value of capacitor is 100nF.

Opamp rail voltages are 10.6V and ground.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a simulation tool?

Comment: @Haseeb Use a spice tool (like LT spice to simulate this)

Answer (score 0):

The function of the switch is to interrupt the resistive feedback to the amplifier, so that (due to the feedback capacitor C39) the
output slew rate becomes slow.

That has the effect of sampling the sum of the input signals, and
holding that sum value nearly constant for the OFF time of the
analog switch.

As for the transistor Q6, it seems to clamp the amplifier input
so that  it cannot drop below about 4.7V; that's a mystery
to me.  Is the transistor base really held at constant voltage?

Comment: Yes thats also what confusing me transistor is constantly being held at that voltage, so I keep asking this question why even bother it putting there when it is constantly ON.

Comment: @HaseebZaib - Hi, You posted that text as an "answer", in the "Your Answer" box below. Please note that Stack Exchange is not like typical internet forums & only *answers* to the question at the top of the page should be written in that box. In this case, it was clear you were trying to reply to this answer, so I moved your post to become a comment here. You will see more site rules and etiquette explained in the [tour] and [help]. Please use comments to reply to answers (if needed) & edit the question to add any updates. Do not use the "Your Answer" box, unless you are adding a final solution

Comment: @HaseebZaib  The op amp, if it actually is operating, regulates the input pin at its 6V point, so clamping would presumably not occur in normal operation; that makes the operation of the transistor a load (current sink) and has the effect of making a logarithmic response.   Ideal-diode in feedback is one way of making a logarithm amplifier.   The resistor R46, though, dominates if output is high (and transistor shuts off)